# Request jenkins rest api using the authtoken got from by organization's SSO

Tags: jenkins, single-sign-on, auth-token

I have a webportal where user login using our organization's SSO, After logging in i get the authtoken for the logged in session. 
And currently i have the Jenkins authentication setup using organization LDAP.

From our webportal we will be issuing some jenkins REST APIs. I can see jenkins support API token for the REST APIs. 
1. All our jenkins users don't have the token generated
2. Even they do generate, we will have to map each users id with token , which would be very bad.

Is there any way to execute rest api with the auth token got from SSO login ?

Comment: Could you provide more details about SSO technology used in your case? SAML, Kerberos, OpenId, something else?

Comment: Its SAML based hosted in azure

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have similar issue.